# Concat array's elements of a DataFrame's column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Dataframe df1 formated as below:

```
+--------------------------+
|DateInfos                 |
+--------------------------+
|[[3, A, 111], [4, B, 222]]|
|[[1, C, 333], [2, D, 444]]|
|[[5, E, 555]]             |
+--------------------------+
```

I would like to concat the second and third element of each tuples3 with the separator "-" (df2):

```
+------------------------+
|DateInfos               |
+------------------------+
|[[3, A-111], [4, B-222]]|
|[[1, C-333], [2, D-444]]|
|[[5, E-555]]            |
+------------------------+
```

I print the schema of df1:

```
root
 |-- DateInfos: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- _1: integer (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- _2: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- _3: string (nullable = true)
```

I assume I have to create an udf which use a function with the following signature:

```
def concatDF1(array: Array[(Int, String, String)]): Array[(Int, String)] = {
   val res = Array.map(elem => (elem._1, elem._2 + "-" + elem._3)).toArray
   res
}
```

I execute the method like this:

```
val concat_udf = sqlContext.udf.register("concat_udf", concat _)
val df2_temp = df1.withColumn("DataInfos_temp",concat_udf(df1("DataInfos")))
val df2 = df2_temp.drop("DataInfos").withColumnRenamed("DataInfos_temp", "DataInfos")
```

I obtain this error:

```
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function(anonfun$4: (array<struct<_1:int,_2:string,_3:string>>) => array<struct<_1:int,_2:string>>)
```

Do you have any idea?

Comment: which version of spark you are using? can consider `concat_ws` function which takes a string separator as the first argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val sparkSession = ...
import sparkSession.implicits._

val input = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  Seq((3, "A", 111), (4, "B", 222)),
  Seq((1, "C", 333), (2, "D", 444)),
  Seq((5, "E", 555))
)).toDF("DateInfos")

val concatElems = udf { seq: Seq[Row] =>
  seq.map { case Row(x: Int, y: String, z: Int) => 
    (x, s"$y-$z")
  }
}

val output = input.select(concatElems($"DateInfos").as("DateInfos"))

output.show(truncate = false)
```

Which outputs:

```
+----------------------+
|DateInfos             |
+----------------------+
|[[3,A-111], [4,B-222]]|
|[[1,C-333], [2,D-444]]|
|[[5,E-555]]           |
+----------------------+
```